# Make Part look like Section and make Section look like paragraph; but with all the numbering preserved?

Tags: sectioning, paragraphs, sections-paragraphs, parts, section-titles

So I am trying to write a book summary, a few pages long. Is there any way to make `part` look just like `section`, except preserving the Roman numbering for `part`; and make `section` look just like `paragraph`, except preserving the Arabic numbering for `section`? I tried with the following commands:

```
\let\part\section
\def\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\let\section\paragraph
\def\theparagraph{\arabic{paragraph}}
```

In some way, it worked for `part`; but it doesn't work for `section`, as once let `section` behave like `paragraph`, I can't add any numbering to it anymore...

Edit: I also need to make sure numbering of the `paragraph`-ized `section` not affected by the `section`-ized `part`; i.e., make the section numbers continue regardless of parts

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Please clarify what exactly you mean with: "make part look just like section". Is  https://i.stack.imgur.com/rk5EF.png the output you expect?

Comment: @leandriis yes, but the problem is for paragraphs, `\arabic{paragraph}` can't assign a number to it...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what it is that you want but why not just use `\section` and `\paragraph` while changing the style of their numbering?

```
\documentclass{article} % ????
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{chngcntr} % for changing how counters get incremented
\counterwithout{subsection}{section} % continuous subsection numbering
\counterwithout{subsubsection}{subsection} % continuous subsubsection numbering
\counterwithout{paragraph}{subsubsection} % continuous paragraph numbering

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\arabic{paragraph}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} % number \paragraph in document
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}    % put \paragraph in ToC

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]
\paragraph{First paragraph}
\lipsum[2]
\paragraph{Second paragraph}
\lipsum[2]
\section{A section}
\lipsum[1]
\paragraph{A paragraph}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

In response to your comment I have added code so that paragraph numbering is continuous.

Comment: but is there any way to make paragraph numbering not affected by section numbering? e.g., when starting a new section, is there any way to let the paragraph numbering continue instead of restarting with 1?

Comment: @KaiYang I have extended my answer. Pity you didn't include the constraint in your original question.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, I just updated the original question